# How to achieve 2 decimal places even on zero values in Teradata SQL Assistant?

Tags: sql-server, teradata, currency, teradata-sql-assistant

Below is the code in MS SQL Server

```
FORMAT(CAST(a.[Sample_Column] as numeric(10,2)), 'C', 'en-US')
```

I want to achieve the same in Teradata, for which I tried the below:

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR (cast(tmp."Sample_Column" as decimal(10,2)), '$99,999,999.00' ))
```

Issue is when the Sample column has values as '0', its populating '.00' in Teradata. I want it to be populated as '0.00' instead.

Comment: What's the datatype of Samle_Column?

Comment: The datatype of Samle_Column is VARCHAR(100)

Answer (score 1):

You must specify `0` in the format to avoid leading blanks.

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR (cast("Sample_Column" as decimal(10,2)), '$999,999,990.00'))
```

If `"Sample_Column"` is numeric, there's no need for a CAST:

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR ("Sample_Column", '$999,999,990.00'))
```

The currency sign might be supplied using NLS_PARAMS:

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR ("Sample_Column", 'L999,999,990.00', 'NLS_CURRENCY = ''$'''));
```